# Using a link to submit form in jQuery won't work

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, post

I have a small form and a link which submits this form using jQuery and POST. I wish to display the HTML output from the process page on the form page without refreshing using AJAX. However, my code doesn't seem to work when I click my submit link. Please can someone point out what I may be doing wrong here? Many thanks.

Regards

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js">

</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#myform').submit(function() {
                $.post('demoprocess.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
                    $('#results').html(data);
                });
            });
});
    </script>

<form name="myform" id="myform" action="" method="POST">  
    <label for="name" id="name_label">Name</label>  
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value=""/><br>>

    <label for="email" id="email_label">Email</label>  
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="30" value=""/><br>

    <a href="#" title="" class="pay-button" style="margin-top:5px;" onclick="document.myform.submit()">SUBMIT</a> 
</form>

<!-- We will output the results from demoprocess.php here -->
<div id="results"><div>
```

Comment: try `<a href="#" title="" class="pay-button" style="margin-top:5px;" onclick="$('#myform').submit();">SUBMIT</a>`

Comment: Your code is missing a `});` to close the `document.ready` handler. Is this a typo? It could be causing the problem if not.

Comment: Thanks Rory, there was a typo, but it still won't work

Answer (score 5):

The trouble is that you are binding a *jQuery* `submit` handler but firing the *native DOM* `submit` method. This does not fire a `submit` event, so the jQuery handler is never notified.

You should trigger the event with jQuery instead. It's probably also easiest to do this in jQuery, rather than using an `onclick` attribute:

```
$('.pay-button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the link's default behaviour
    $('#myForm').submit(); // trigget the submit handler
});
```

Note that this isn't very good design, IMO, because users without Javascript will not be able to submit your form.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your form doesn't contain any element that fires the javascript `submit` event

**From jquery Documentation [`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)**:

> The submit event is sent to an element when the user is attempting to submit a form. It can only be attached to  elements. Forms can be submitted either by clicking an explicit `<input type="submit">`, `<input type="image">`, or `<button type="submit">`, or by pressing Enter when certain form elements have focus.

So, in order to make `.submit()` works you need to add one of:

- `<input type="submit">`,
- `<input type="image">`,
- or `<button type="submit">`.

  to your form, so you will need to add something like:

  ```
  <input type="submit" />
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
document.forms[0].submit()
```

or

```
$('#myform').submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try preventing the default behaviour on form submission:

```
$('#myform').submit(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    $.post('demoprocess.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
        $('#results').html(data);
    });
});
```